# Where can I get the Blackberry 10 Alpha Dev Kit from?

Tags: blackberry-10

Is there a download location and dev guidance?

Comment: What have you tried? Any ways if you search "Blackberry 10 aplha developer kit" on google, you will get this to links which can be really useful https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/using_the_bb10_simulator_2008466_11.html and https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberry10devalphas/faq

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the [Dev Alpha device](https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberry10devalphas/) given to developers to help them test their apps on BlackBerry 10, you will need to attend one of the BlackBerry Jam (for developing consumer apps) or Enterprise Jam (for developing enterprise apps) events and qualify for a device.

- Jam events: http://www.blackberryjamconference.com/
- Enterprise Jam events: http://www.blackberryjamenterprise.com/